# Order by enum description

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC projet using EF code first, and I am facing a situation where I need to order by an enum description:

```
public partial class Item
{
    public enum MyEnumE
    {
        [Description("description of enum1")]
        Enum1,
        [Description("description of enum2")]
        Enum2,
        ...
    }

    public MyEnumE MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the `Search` and `SortAndPaginate` functions:

```
public async Task<IPagedList<Item>> Search(ItemCriteria criteria, SortableTypeE sortName, SortOrder.TypeE sortOrder, int pageNb)
    {
        var itemFilter = GenerateFilter(criteria);
        var items = entities.Items.Where(itemFilter);

        return await SortAndPaginate(items, sortName, sortOrder, pageNb);
    }

    private async Task<IPagedList<Item>> SortAndPaginate(IQueryable<Item> items, SortableTypeE sortName, SortOrder.TypeE sortOrder, int pageNb)
    {
        IOrderedQueryable<Item> result = null;

        switch (sortName)
        {
            ...
            case SortableTypeE.Type:
                result = sortOrder == SortOrder.TypeE.ASC
                    ? items.OrderBy(i => i.MyEnum.GetDescription())
                    : items.OrderByDescending(i => i.MyEnum.GetDescription());
                result = result.ThenBy(i => i.SomeOtherProperty);
                break;
            ...
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            return await result.ToPagedListAsync(pageNb, 10);
        }

        return PagedListHelper.Empty<Item>();
    }
```

The problem is that the `Item` table can be quite huge.
I thought about calling `ToListAsync` right after `entities.Items.Where(itemFilter)` but this will get back all filtered items although I only need one page. Does not sound like a good idea.

But if I don't do that `EF` won't know about `GetDescription()` mathod and I can only think about two solutions:
- Change my database column to a string (the enum description) instead of the enum itself (but sounds like a hack to me)
- Or alphabetically order `MyEnumE` components directly in the `enum` declaration (seems dirty and quite unmaintainable too)

I'm quite stuck since I'm concerned about performances if I call `ToListAsync` right after filtering, all other solutions seem dirty, and I absolutely need a `IPagedList` returned from the `Search` method.

Would anyone have an idea about how to deal with this issue ?

Thanks a lot.

***UPDATE***

Here is the `GetDescription` method (can change it if necessary):

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum e)
{
    FieldInfo fi = e.GetType().GetField(e.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return e.ToString();
}
```

***SOLUTIONS***

I'll finally go for Ivan Stoev's suggestion because my project is mainly based on `Linq` (using `Linq` instead of stored procedures etc.), so this solution seems more suitable to my particular case than creating reference tables.

However `Niyoko Yuliawan`'s and `Michael Freidgeim`'s are also really good answers to me, anyone reading this post and having a more database approach should go for their solutions ;)

Thanks a lot to all of you.

Comment: Can you post the `GetDescription` method?

Comment: Sorry, did not see your comment :( It posted it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would go with dynamic expression. It's more flexible and can easily be changed w/o affecting the database tables and queries.

However, instead of sorting by description strings in the database, I would create ordered map in memory, associating `int` "order" value with each enum value like this:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, int>> DescriptionOrder<TSource, TEnum>(this Expression<Func<TSource, TEnum>> source)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var body = ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(enumType))
            .OrderBy(value => value.GetDescription())
            .Select((value, ordinal) => new { value, ordinal })
            .Reverse()
            .Aggregate((Expression)null, (next, item) => next == null ? (Expression)
                Expression.Constant(item.ordinal) :
                Expression.Condition(
                    Expression.Equal(source.Body, Expression.Constant(item.value)),
                    Expression.Constant(item.ordinal),
                    next));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, int>>(body, source.Parameters[0]);
    }

    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
        where TEnum : struct
    {
        var enumType = typeof(TEnum);
        if (!enumType.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
        var field = typeof(TEnum).GetField(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        return field.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ?? name;
    }
}
```

The usage would be like this:

```
case SortableTypeE.Type:
    var order = EnumHelper.DescriptionOrder((Item x) => x.MyEnum);
    result = sortOrder == SortOrder.TypeE.ASC
        ? items.OrderBy(order)
        : items.OrderByDescending(order);
    result = result.ThenBy(i => i.SomeOtherProperty);
    break;
```

which would generate expression like this:

```
x => x.MyEnum == Enum[0] ? 0 :
     x.MyEnum == Enum[1] ? 1 :
     ...
     x.MyEnum == Enum[N-2] ? N - 2 :
     N - 1;
```

where 0,1,..N-2 is the corresponding index in the value list sorted by description.

Comment: The more flexible approach will be the one that can easily be changed w/o affecting the code by updating data in database tables. All in-memory solutions will not work well for paging on big tables, because you have to retrieve the whole table before doing any sorting

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim First off, this is database solution, not-in memory (the expression will be translated to `CASE WHEN` SQL expression and performed by the database). Second, it can easily handle dynamic localization, adding new members etc. which is harder with database table. And EF is for writing C# queries, not pure SQL reports.

Comment: I realize this is an older post, but anyone know how to make this work with an Enum that has more than 10 values, so as to avoid the `Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.` Error?

Comment: @ewahner Nesting is already fixed in EFC 5.0 (coming next month). If you can't wait, you can modify the code to use `+` instead, e.g. `(x.MyEnum == Enum[0]  ? 1 : 0) + (x.MyEnum == Enum[1] ? 2 : 0)  + ... + (x.MyEnum == Enum[N-1] ? N : 0)`

Comment: @IvanStoev if I understand you correctly, you are saying that I would change the Expression.Condition to Expression.Add and then instead of passing source.parameters[0], I would pass source.parameters ???? I hope I got that wrong because when I tried that the query timed out.

Comment: @ewahner Something like: `var body = ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(enumType)).OrderBy(value => value.GetDescription()).Select((value, ordinal) => (Expression)Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(source.Body, Expression.Constant(value)), Expression.Constant(ordinal + 1), Expression.Constant(0))).Aggregate(Expression.Add);`

Comment: Quite nice idea. One small thing - if you use "where T : Enum" then you will not need the check "if (!enumType.IsEnum)". So a shorter content for the GetDescription method would be just "FieldInfo/var field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());" ... and then the extraciton of the Description of the attribute.  Also a check for DisplayAttribute could be added.

Comment: @VasilPopov Sure. Just back in 2016 when I posted this, there was no `Enum` constraint :)

Answer (score 6):

### Alternative 1

You can do it by projecting enum into custom value and sort by it.

Example:

```
items
    .Select(x=> new 
    {
        x,
        Desc = (
            x.Enum == Enum.One ? "Desc One" 
            : x.Enum == Enum.Two ? "Desc Two" 
            ... and so on)
    })
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Desc)
    .Select(x=>x.x);
```

Entity framework then will generate SQL something like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN Enum = 1 THEN 'Desc One'
    WHEN Enum = 2 THEN 'Desc Two'
    ...and so on
    END
```

If you have a lot of query like this, you can create extension method

```
public static IQueryable<Entity> OrderByDesc(this IQueryable<Entity> source)
{
    return source.Select(x=> new 
    {
        x,
        Desc = (
            x.Enum == Enum.One ? "Desc One" 
            : x.Enum == Enum.Two ? "Desc Two" 
            ... and so on)
    })
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Desc)
    .Select(x=>x.x);
}
```

And call it when you need it

```
var orderedItems = items.OrderByDesc();
```

---

### Alternative 2

Another alternative solution is to create additional table that map enum value to enum description and join your table to this table. This solution will be more performant because you can create index on enum description column.

---

### Alternative 3

If you want dynamic expression based on your enum description attribute, you can build yourself

#### Helper Class

```
public class Helper
{
    public MyEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

#### Get dynamically built expression

```
public static string GetDesc(MyEnum e)
{
    var type = typeof(MyEnum);
    var memInfo = type.GetMember(e.ToString());
    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
        false);
    return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
}

private static Expression<Func<MyEntity, Helper>> GetExpr()
{
    var descMap = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
        .Cast<MyEnum>()
        .ToDictionary(value => value, GetDesc);

    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyEntity), "x");
    var expr = (Expression) Expression.Constant(string.Empty);
    foreach (var desc in descMap)
    {
        // Change string "Enum" below with your enum property name in entity
        var prop = Expression.Property(paramExpr, typeof(MyEntity).GetProperty("Enum")); 
        expr = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(prop, Expression.Constant(desc.Key)),
            Expression.Constant(desc.Value), expr);
    }


    var newExpr = Expression.New(typeof(Helper));

    var bindings = new MemberBinding[]
    {
        Expression.Bind(typeof(Helper).GetProperty("Entity"), paramExpr),
        Expression.Bind(typeof(Helper).GetProperty("Description"), expr)
    };

    var body = Expression.MemberInit(newExpr, bindings);

    return (Expression<Func<MyEntity, Helper>>) Expression.Lambda(body, paramExpr);
}
```

#### Call it like this

```
var e = GetExpr();
items.Select(e)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Description)
    .Select(x => x.Entity);
```

Comment: I don't think that the first solution is a good idea since, if I understand correctly, this would duplicate the enum descriptions everywhere I need to sort by it. However the idea of creating a map table sound cleaner than the other choices. Since those enums are accessed very often, to your opinion won't it  have performance issue to refer to another table everytime ?

Comment: @Flash_Back If you don't want to duplicate description, you can build expression dynamically. It will be a little complicated, but it's possible. Wait my edit, I will show you how to do it.

Comment: @Flash_Back Answer updated with dynamically built expression

Comment: @Flash_Back: Refer to indexed reference table should be quick , and SQL will cache the data

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I don't know what to choose in Niyoko Yuliawan's suggestions, if I go for reference tables I will have to create at least 21 "enum tables" while I currently have 21 tables. I would multiply by two, isn't it too much ?

Comment: @Flash_Back Actually alternative 2 is preferred solution. 21 tables is not much.

Comment: @Flash_Back if your 21 enums are similar (e.g. colors of shows, colors of socks etc), you can put them in one reference table with extra column TypeOfMyProperty

Answer (score 1):

> Change my database column to a string (the enum description) instead
>   of the enum itself (but sounds like a hack to me).

Opposite, for data-driven application it's better to describe Item property in **the database reference table** MyItemProperty(MyPropKey,MyPropDescription) and have MyPropKey column in your Items table.

It has a few benefits, e.g.

- allow to add new property values without need to change code;
- allow to write SQL reports having all information in the database without writing c#;
- performance optimisation can be done on SQL
  level just by requesting one page;
- no enum - less code to   maintain.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple and with a good performance, I would order the enum manually, you only have to do it once, and it will help a lot

```
public enum MyEnumE
{
    Enum1 = 3,
    Enum2 = 1,
    Enum3 = 2, // set the order here... 
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought about that but I does not sound very maintainable to me, whenever a description has to be changed, I'll have to re-order the enum manually, and there might be errors if the enum contains lots of entries. But for the moment it seems like the best solution anyway, I'll accept it if there is no better one ;)

Comment: If you enum changes constantly, then using an enum is maybe not what you need

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example using a join:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public partial class Item
    {
        public enum MyEnumE
        {
            [Description("description of enum1")]
            Enum1,
            [Description("description of enum2")]
            Enum2
        }

        public Item(MyEnumE myEnum)
        {
            MyEnum = myEnum;
        }

        public MyEnumE MyEnum { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> GetEnumRanks(Type enumType)
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType);
            var results = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(values.Length);

            foreach (int value in values)
            {
                FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumType.GetField(Enum.GetName(enumType, value));
                var attribute = (DescriptionAttribute)fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute));
                results.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(value, attribute.Description));
            }

            return results.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x.Key, i));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var itemsList = new List<Item>();
            itemsList.Add(new Item(Item.MyEnumE.Enum1));
            itemsList.Add(new Item(Item.MyEnumE.Enum2));
            itemsList.Add(new Item(Item.MyEnumE.Enum2));
            itemsList.Add(new Item(Item.MyEnumE.Enum1));

            IQueryable<Item> items = itemsList.AsQueryable();

            var descriptions = GetEnumRanks(typeof(Item.MyEnumE));

            //foreach (var i in descriptions)
            //  Console.WriteLine(i.Value);

            var results = items.Join(descriptions, a => (int)a.MyEnum, b => b.Key, (x, y) => new { Item = x, Rank = y.Value }).OrderBy(x => x.Rank).Select(x => x.Item);

            foreach (var i in results)
                Console.WriteLine(i.MyEnum.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to solve, only that my ordering had to be **dynamic**, that is the sort by column parameter is a `string`.

The `boolean` sorting also had to be customized in that sense that `true` comes before `false` (e.g. 'Active' is before 'Inactive').

I'm sharing here the complete code with you, so you can spare your time. In case you find spots for improvement, please feel free to share in a comment.

```
private static IQueryable<T> OrderByDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, SortField sortField)
{
    var queryParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var orderByPropertyExpression = GetPropertyExpression(sortField.FieldName, queryParameterExpression);

    Type orderByPropertyType = orderByPropertyExpression.Type;
    LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(orderByPropertyExpression, queryParameterExpression);

    if (orderByPropertyType.IsEnum)
    {
        orderByPropertyType = typeof(int);
        lambdaExpression = GetExpressionForEnumOrdering<T>(lambdaExpression);
    }
    else if (orderByPropertyType == typeof(bool))
    {
        orderByPropertyType = typeof(string);
        lambdaExpression =
            GetExpressionForBoolOrdering(orderByPropertyExpression, queryParameterExpression);
    }

    var orderByExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        sortField.SortDirection == SortDirection.Asc ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
        new Type[] { typeof(T), orderByPropertyType },
        query.Expression,
        Expression.Quote(lambdaExpression));

    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(orderByExpression);
}
```

The shared `GetPropertyExpression` has been simplified a bit, to exclude the nested property handling.

```
private static MemberExpression GetPropertyExpression(string propertyName, ParameterExpression queryParameterExpression)
{
    MemberExpression result = Expression.Property(queryParameterExpression, propertyName);
    return result;
}
```

Here is the slightly modified code (from the accepted solution) to handle the `Enum` ordering.

```
private static Expression<Func<TSource, int>> GetExpressionForEnumOrdering<TSource>(LambdaExpression source)
{
    var enumType = source.Body.Type;
    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var body = ((int[])Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        .OrderBy(value => GetEnumDescription(value, enumType))
        .Select((value, ordinal) => new { value, ordinal })
        .Reverse()
        .Aggregate((Expression)null, (next, item) => next == null ? (Expression)
            Expression.Constant(item.ordinal) :
            Expression.Condition(
                Expression.Equal(source.Body, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(item.value), enumType)),
                Expression.Constant(item.ordinal),
                next));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, int>>(body, source.Parameters[0]);
}
```

And the `boolean` ordering as well.

```
private static LambdaExpression GetExpressionForBoolOrdering(MemberExpression orderByPropertyExpression, ParameterExpression queryParameterExpression)
{
    var firstWhenActiveExpression = Expression.Condition(orderByPropertyExpression,
        Expression.Constant("A"),
        Expression.Constant("Z"));

    return Expression.Lambda(firstWhenActiveExpression, new[] { queryParameterExpression });
}
```

Also the `GetEnumDescription` has been modified to receive the `Type` as the parameter, so it can be called without a generic.

```
private static string GetEnumDescription(int value, Type enumType)
{
    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var name = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);
    var field = enumType.GetField(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
    return field.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>()?.Description ?? name;
}
```

The `SortField` is a simple abstraction containing the `string` column property to be sorted upon and the `direction` of the sort. For the sake of simplicity I am also not sharing that one here.

Cheers!