# Linq expression for ordering entities based on static values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project using EF code first and I would need to build a `Linq expression` in order to order `Item` entities based on a static dictionary values.

```
public partial class Item
{
    public enum TypeE
    {
        Type1,
        Type2,
        Type3,
        Type4,
    }

    public TypeE Type { get; set; } // Mapped database column

    public static Dictionary<TypeE, int> MyDic = new Dictionary<TypeE, int>()
    {
        { TypeE.Type1, 42 },
        { TypeE.Type2, 16 },
        { TypeE.Type3, 0 },
        { TypeE.Type4, 34 },
    };
}
```

My final aim would be some method working in `Linq to entities` and that would allow me to achieve something like `myEntities.OrderBy(i => Item.MyDic[i.Type])`.

I've to precise that I can not use `AsEnumerable()` or anything else enumerating the entities collection, I really need something working directly in `Linq to entities`.
I also would like to avoid creating reference tables in the database, I'm really looking for a `Linq expression`.

A few days ago, I asked a quite similar question about how to sort entities by an enum description and the answer given by Ivan Stoev (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40203664/2828106) perfectly achieved what I wanted.
If there was a way to reuse this kind of logic for this new purpose this would be great but I was not experimented enough, I ended up with an infinite loop while trying.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the same approach utilized for dictionary:

```
public static class Expressions
{
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, int>> DictionaryOrder<TSource, TKey, TOrder>(Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> source, IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TOrder> by)
    {
        var body = by
            .OrderBy(entry => entry.Value)
            .Select((entry, ordinal) => new { entry.Key, ordinal })
            .Reverse()
            .Aggregate((Expression)null, (next, item) => next == null ? (Expression)
                Expression.Constant(item.ordinal) :
                Expression.Condition(
                    Expression.Equal(source.Body, Expression.Constant(item.Key)),
                    Expression.Constant(item.ordinal),
                    next));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, int>>(body, source.Parameters[0]);
    }
}
```

and the sample usage:

```
var order = Expressions.DictionaryOrder((Item x) => x.Type, Item.MyDic);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for answering again, this works perfectly fine. I tried to modify your previous `Enum` method but from what I can see here I was not going the right way at all.