# linq Custom ordering without taking all records

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I have database(SQL server) table with over 100k records. Table contains enum (smallInt in DB) which has 0-5 values.(C# for front end) I am writing code for fetching the top 10 records ordered by that enum. **I want custom ordering**. like records with enum value 2 should come first then 4 then 3 and likewise.

I don't want to get all records and then sort it using icomparer then take top 10. How should i write that linq statement. Even SQL command is also fine for me.

Comment: what is your top 10 criteria?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268347/linq-expression-for-ordering-entities-based-on-static-values?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202415/order-by-enum-description/40203664#40203664).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Temporary Table `[#EnumOrder]` with `Enum` value mapping to the order you want. Then inner join with your table, and order by the `Order` column

```
CREATE TABLE [#EnumOrder] (
    [Enum] SMALLINT
    ,[Order] SMALLINT
    )

    INSERT INTO [#EnumOrder]
    VALUES 
    (2, 1), 
    (4, 2), 
    (3, 3), 
    (5, 4), 
    (0, 5),
    (1, 6)

SELECT TOP 10 t.*
FROM dbo.[YourTable] t
INNER JOIN [#EnumOrder] o ON t.EnumColumn = o.Enum
ORDER BY o.[Order]

DROP TABLE [#EnumOrder]
```

Now records will be sorted in this order: 2, 4, 3, 5, 0 and 1. You can always change the values you want to insert to `[#EnumOrder]` table to get the order you want.