OData orderby Enum Type throws exception
I have an entity defined as follows, which encounters issues when trying to sort by the TheType property:
[Serializable]
[Authorize]
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class TheEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique Identifier
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tenant Id. Non-configurable
    /// </summary>
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(TheTypeEnum))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public TheTypeEnum? TheType { get; set; }
}

In my OData query, TheType is represented as a varchar field in the database.
For eg: The OData query looks like http://localhost/odata/theEntity?$orderby=theType
The function handling this query is:
public async Task<ApiResponse<IQueryable<TheEntity>>> QueryTheEntities(ODataQueryOptions<TheEntity> options)
{
    var response = new ApiResponse<IQueryable<TheEntity>>();

    try
    {
        int maxTop = options.Top?.Value ?? options.Context?.DefaultQuerySettings?.MaxTop ?? MAX_RESULTS;
        var query = await scopedRepository
            .TheEntity
            .GetQueryAsync(mapper: mapper, options, new QuerySettings());
            
        response.Data = query.Take(maxTop);
    }
    catch (ODataException ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "OData query failed.");
        response.ModelState.AddModelError("OData options", "One or more parameters in the OData query are invalid.");
    }

    return response;
}

However, when attempting to order by TheType, I receive the following exception:

The LINQ expression DbSet<TheEntity>().Where(s => s.TenantId == __scope_TenantId_0) .OrderBy(s => s.TheType == null ? null : (TheTypeEnum?)Enum.Parse<TheTypeEnum>(s.TheType)) could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.Enum.Parse' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Here's the LINQ expression properly formatted
DbSet<TheEntity>()
    .Where(s => s.TenantId == __scope_TenantId_0)
    .OrderBy(s => 
        s.TheType == null ? null : (TheTypeEnum?)Enum.Parse<TheTypeEnum>(s.TheType)
    )

From this exception, it seems that sorting by `TheType` is not supported at the database level due to the use of `Enum.Parse`. I would like to avoid loading the entire dataset into memory, as it is quite large. Is there a way to perform this sorting efficiently at the database level without resorting to client-side evaluation?
Tried the below, but  no luck.
        foreach (var orderByNode in orderByClause.OrderByNodes)
        {
            if (orderByNode is OrderByPropertyNode propertyNode)
            {
                var propertyName = propertyNode.Property.Name;
                var isDescending = propertyNode.Direction == OrderByDirection.Descending;
            

                if (IsEnumProperty(propertyName))
                {
                    // Order by the underlying integer value of the enum
                    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Simulation), "sim");
                    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
                    var convertToInt = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(int));  // Convert enum to int

                    var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Simulation, int>>(convertToInt, parameter);

                    orderedQuery = orderedQuery == null
                        ? query.OrderBy(orderByExpression)
                        : isDescending ? orderedQuery.ThenByDescending(orderByExpression) : orderedQuery.ThenBy(orderByExpression);
                }
            }

        }


The problem is in the LINQ expression. EF Core try it's best to translate LINQ expressions directly to SQL so it can be server evaluated, but it can't translate everything, in your case Enum.Parse<TheTypeEnum>(...)., you'll need to somehow get OData to generate a LINQ expression that can be translated to SQL.

[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202415/order-by-enum-description
Tried the answer from this link.
EnumHelper.DescriptionOrder<Entity, TheType>((Entity x) => (TheTypeEnum)x.TheType);
But no luck either.

Is it possible that we translate the Enum value to string and using the string value in Linq expression？
